# Using Revit API draw dimension from gridline to sleeve (Speciality equipment)

Tags: revit-api, revit

[Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viFkp.png)  Using Revit API when we apply Dimension from Grid line to Sleeve (Specialty equipment) that time  Revit returns an error message .from error message if i click "Cancel" option deletes the dimensions  and if i click the "remove reference" button that time some dimension are deleted.

[image: Error image - Reference of highlighted dimension no longer parallel]

Comment: Please provide some code for us to review.

Comment: Yes,  i add some code in - Source code image

Answer (score 0):

Create a dimension that works manually through the user interface first, then use RevitLookup to analyse its properties and find out what exact references it has picked up. In general, if a feature is not available in the Revit product manually through the user interface, then the Revit API will not provide it either.